# Pytho Kafka, Spark Streaming, Mongodb conection

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, streaming, spark, apache-kafka

Olá

Estou criando uma job streaming, porém não recebo mensagem de erro e nem acontece a gravação no mongo.

Já tentei diversos tipos de conexão. Na linha de comando, producer e consumer consigo produzir e consumir o tópico normalmente.

Agradeço desde já!

Segue o meu código:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from pymongo import MongoClient
from json import loads
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import logging

spark = SparkSession.builder \
     .appName("edp_ignite_streaming") \
     .master("yarn") \
     .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://172.29.0.22:27017/ignite.DDATransaction") \
     .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://172.29.0.22:27017/ignite.DDATransaction") \
     .getOrCreate()

logger = logging.getLogger('ignite_consumer.py')

logger.debug("TESTE PARA VER SE O LOGGER ESTA FUNCIONANDO. DULOREAN")

print("INICIANDO CONTEXTO SPARK ")
sc = spark.sparkContext
print("INICIANDO CONTEXTO SPARK STREAMING")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
print("INICIANDO CONTEXTO SPARK SQL")

#sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

logger.debug("CONSUMINDO O TOPICO")
consumer = KafkaConsumer('edp_ignite_teste',
                         bootstrap_servers=['kafka02.medp.pt:6667'],
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                         enable_auto_commit=True,
                         group_id='ignite-group',
                         value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

consumerKStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topics = ['edp_ignite_teste'], kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": 'kafka02.medp.pt:6667'})

streamingDataFrame.writeStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("topic", "edp_ignite_topic_1") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka01.medp.pt:6667")\
     .start()

consumerKStream.show()

client = MongoClient('172.29.0.22:27017')
collection = client.ignite.DDATransaction

logger.debug("ITERANDO A LISTA PARA PERSISTENCIA. DULOREAN")
for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
    collection.insert_one(message)
    print('{} added to {}'.format(message, collection))



df = sparkSession.read.format('com.stratio.datasource.mongodb').options(host='172.29.0.22:27017', database='ignite', collection='DDATransaction').load()
df.select("column1").collect()

df.select("column1").write.format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").mode('overwrite').options(host='172.29.0.22:27017', database='ignite', collection='DDATransaction').save()
dfView = sparkSession.read.format('com.stratio.datasource.mongodb').options(host='172.29.0.22:27017', database='ignite', collection='DDATransaction').load()
dfView.show()




logger.debug("DATAFRAME DE TESTE. DULOREAN")

people = spark.createDataFrame([("Bilbo Baggins",  50), ("Gandalf", 1000), ("Thorin", 195), ("Balin", 178), ("Kili", 77),
   ("Dwalin", 169), ("Oin", 167), ("Gloin", 158), ("Fili", 82), ("Bombur", None)], ["name", "age"])

people.write.format("mongo").mode("append").save()
people.write.format("mongo").mode("append").option("database","igniteDfTeste").option("collection", "contatos").save()

logger.debug("GRAVACAO MONGO. DULOREAN")
print("Save conta records in mongodb")
df_str.write.format("mongo").mode("append").option("database","ignite").option("collection", "DDATransaction").save()

logger.debug("ENVIO PARA OUTRO TOPICO KAFKA. DULOREAN")

streamingDataFrame.writeStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("topic", "edp_ignite_topic_1") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka01.medp.pt:6667") \
     .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://no01.medp.pt/checkpointkfk/") \
     .start()


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Seu consumer fica no ar via linha de comando enquanto você está rodando a aplicação? Se sim, ambos estão no mesmo consumer  group?